# change color of just one domain label - Android Plot

Tags: android, plot, androidplot

I created an bar chart using android plot.

I want that, after clicking a bar, its matching domain label would change color.

I know how to set all of the domain label colors . using:

```
 plot.getGraphWidget().getDomainLabelPaint().setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

but I would like to change the color of **just one** of the labels.

My domain step is:

```
 plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 1);
```

I changed the domain's format with this:

```
  plot.setDomainValueFormat(new Format() {

        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(final Object obj,
                final StringBuffer toAppendTo, final FieldPosition pos) {
            final int index = ((Number) obj).intValue();
            return new StringBuffer("").append((char) (index + 'A'));
        }

        @Override
        public Object parseObject(final String string,
                final ParsePosition position) {
            return null;
        }

    });
```

I have two ideas (which I fail to do):

1) can I change the color of a domain label string, by extending the Format class (in the methods above)?
OR
2) can I draw another set of of domain labels on top of the existing ones?(that would be with different color)

Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next build of Androidplot will contain a new class and a couple new methods that can be used to accomplish this.  For now, [here's a development build](https://androidplot.jira.com/builds/artifact/ANDROIDPLOT-TRUNK0/JOB1/build-17/Jars/androidplot-core-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) that contains this new functionality.  The new class is com.androidplot.util.Mapping and the new methods of interested will be added to com.androidplot.xy.XYGraphWidget.  They are:

```
public void setDomainLabelPaintMap(Mapping<Paint, Number> domainLabelPaintMap)
public void setRangeLabelPaintMap(Mapping<Paint, Number> rangeLabelPaintMap)
```

Here's a quick example of how they can be used:

```
plot.getGraphWidget().setRangeLabelPaintMap(new Mapping<Paint, Number>() {

    private Paint customPaint;

    {
        // configure Paint instances either programmatically
        // (as shown here) or use Configurator to initialize via XML.
        customPaint = new Paint();
        customPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public Paint get(Number number) {
        if(number.doubleValue() > 1) {
            return customPaint;
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```